# Kendo UI datepicker Tab key toggling not working in firefox when changing the actual dates of it

Tags: jquery, firefox, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

Am facing this issue guys i have a kendo date picker like

```
 $window.find("#dpkr-pickup-from, #dpkr-pickup-to")
            .kendoDatePicker({ format: "MM/dd/yyyy" })
            .mask("99/99/9999");
```

When i change the actual date

tab key is not working in firefox FYI it works in Chrome.

I have tried with 
ASCII key like

```
$window.find("#dpkr-pickup-from, #dpkr-pickup-to")
            .kendoDatePicker({ format: "MM/dd/yyyy" })
            .mask("99/99/9999")
            .bind("keyup", function () {
                if (e.keyCode === 9) { 
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

no response

Help me to solve this